# Drop row if URL contains a blank space

Tags: python, pandas

I have a comlumn of URLs. some of them are bad and contain blank spaces. I would like to drop the entire row with these bad URLs.

Example URL : https://www.john doe.com

What I have so far is not working:

```
import pandas as pd
 
# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv("Image_Download_drop_spaces.csv")
 
# view dataset
print(df)

 
# drop the rows
print(df.drop(df[df.URL.str.contains(' ')].index))
```

It reads the CSV and prints the df just fine. the issue is in the last line. I dont think I am describing a space correctly, is my assumption.

It errors out and does not drop the rows with spaces. The error is a ValueError: Cannot mask with array containing NA / NaN values

I do not want to remove the space, I want to drop that row.

Comment: what is "not working" ?

Comment: can you point us to the actual issue here? you can filter the records based on your criteria. Or, you can remove the blank spaces and replace them with `''`. For the first, your criterion should be not contains and you won't need that `df.drop`

Comment: It errors out and does not drop the rows with spaces. The error is a ValueError: Cannot mask with array containing NA / NaN values

Answer (score 0):

I would filter as @samkart recommended, but I would negate the criteria (with ~) so that you get all of the instances that DON'T contain a space.

```
df = df[~df.URL.str.contains(' ')]
```

If you want to remove instances that contain a space in the URL or the name:

```
df[~(df.URL.str.contains(' ')|df.name.str.contains(' '))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jim. I do have a second column, 'name',  would this expand to that column as well or will this act only on the URL column? This is why I initially thought a drop row would be the answer.

Comment: You could use this which will remove any rows which have a space in the URL or the name: df = df[~(df.URL.str.contains(' ')|df.name.str.contains(' '))]